# I want to get the HTML/text contents of the Redactor editor

Tags: redactor, javascript, content, editor

I'm building a plugin for Craft CMS. This plugin will load on the edit/content page, where the standard Redactor WYSIWYG editor will be loaded too (by CraftCMS).
I want to get the HTML/text contents of the Redactor editor.

For example `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` will get the HTML contents of the **TinyMCE** editor in WordPress.

How do I achieve this in Craft CMS?

The API documentation says `var text = this.clean.getPlainText(html);`.
But how do I know reference to **this**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I follow, but I think this is what you are looking for.

In your javascript file, you'll want `code.set`

[API Reference](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/code/)

```
...

$('#yourTextArea').redactor('code.set', your.data);
```

Comment: Ignore my last example in the question. I actually wanted to get the code/text out the the editor/textarea, not set the code. But this works too.